# How to resolve AttributeError when creating a WebSocket with PyBit v5 API?

Tags: python, websocket, pybit

I'm trying to create a WebSocket using the new PyBit v5 API, and I'm encountering an issue which is not mentioned in their documentation. I'm attempting to initialize a WebSocket for private channel types with `trace_logging` enabled, but I get an `AttributeError` stating that the module 'websocket' has no attribute 'enableTrace'. Any ideas why I'm having issues with the WebSocket?

```
from pybit.unified_trading import HTTP
from pybit.unified_trading import WebSocket

api_key = "my_api"
api_secret = "my_secret_api"  # obviously not sharing my actual keys

ws_private = WebSocket(
    testnet=True,
    channel_type="private",
    api_key=api_key,
    api_secret=api_secret,
    trace_logging=True
)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\me\Desktop\all random folder\Strategy\test.py", line 9, in <module>
    ws_private = WebSocket(
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pybit\unified_trading.py", line 69, in __init__
    super().__init__(WSS_NAME, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pybit\_websocket_stream.py", line 285, in __init__
    super().__init__(callback_function, ws_name, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pybit\_websocket_stream.py", line 75, in __init__
    websocket.enableTrace(trace_logging)
AttributeError: module 'websocket' has no attribute 'enableTrace'
```